# R:Using a character as argument in a function

Tags: r, function, character

I´m new here and I have not much knowledge in the use of R. I cant find a solution for my current problem: In the use of a character (Path) as an argument for my function.

```
Path <- "C:/...../"

foo <-function(Path){
       Driver  <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=Path"
       connect <- odbcDriverConnect(Driver)
       return(connect)
}
```

My problem is, that Path will be replaced in the function with the quotes. At least I have the following format in my function.

```
...DBQ="C:/..../""
```

I tried to fix this problem with noquote or cat to delete the quotes, but it doesnt help.

I thank you in advance that you are helping a beginner in R :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf()` to insert the `Path`.

```
Path <- "C:/...../"
sprintf("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=\"%s\"", Path)
# [1] "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=\"C:/...../\""
```

So your updated function would be

```
foo <- function(Path) {
    Driver  <- "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=\"%s\""
    connect <- odbcDriverConnect(sprintf(Driver, Path))
    return(connect)
}
```

See `help(sprintf)` for all its amazing uses.

---

**Update:** Since it's not clear to me whether you want the quotes around `Path`, I will include the way to have it without them.  If you **don't** want the quotes in the string, remove them from the `sprintf()` format.

```
Path <- "C:/...../"
sprintf("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=%s", Path)
# [1] "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:/...../"
```

Comment: foo <- function(Path){

   Driver <<- sprintf("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ= %s", Path)
    connect <<- odbcDriverConnect(Driver);
    return(connect)
    }
With this solution I get the correct format:

"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:/...../"
but it still doesnt connect to my database. If I´m replacing the true "path" (not the variable) into the function I can connect.